# API Naming recommendation - findById findByName

Tags: node.js, express, naming

I am creating a new API and researched for some good API naming conventions.

For example you have an API like:

```
GET - /users           | Get all users
GET - /users/:id       | Get user with :id
DELETE - /users/:id    | Delete user with :id
POST - /users          | Create a new user
```

Now I want to add a route for getting a user by name to implement a backend route for autocompletion/typeahead component in frontend.

**Any suggestions for a good naming?**

What do you think about:

```
GET - /users/name/:name       | Get user with :name
```

Comment: You want a single user by name or multiple users by name
If multiple users, in that is the case, then you would use query params and go /users?name=xxx,
Since basically you would be just filtering users 
If single user by name, which is a bit odd, I would say go /name/:name

Comment: That query string stuff makes sense. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Ok, I'll add the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you would basically just filter users, you should use query parameters to pass any filters

```
/users?name=xxx&other=xxx
```

This will allow you to keep your routes clean, and allow you to pass multiple parameters in the future